# External requests via https protocol do not work on android 9

Tags: flutter

I'm new to the framework flutter universe and I'm developing an app for my work it was going well but I came across a problem and I can't get around it.

My problem is as follows I have the home screen of my app where the user must enter a username and password to access until then okay app do the following:

1 - Authenticate the user with Firebase, use it because of notifications;
2 - Authenticating the user in an api developed in php;

One of the employees reported that on the smartphone a samsung galaxy s8 with android 9 is not authenticating, I found it strange and during some tests I noticed that on his smartphone the return received from api is empty, I took his user on my phone and my smartphone worked without problem it's from xiaomi;

Thinking of trying to solve the problem I went into the test lab at samsung and noticed that all smartphones above samsung galaxy s8 with android 9 do not authenticate, but if you take the samsung galaxy s7 that has android 8.0 the authentication goes normally.

Then searching the forum and the internet I noticed that android 9 has undergone a change regarding http requests accepting only https, but the url that access is https and yet I am going through this anomaly because it does not generate any errors.

I also did as described in the link below unsuccessfully resolving the issue.

[Android 9 Http request are fail, Http Request given me error(500 internal serve error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59208569/android-9-http-request-are-fail-http-request-given-me-error500-internal-serve)